# Text Input Field Being Wrapped in <p> tags only for first entry

Tags: channel-entries, text-formatting

I'm running 2.7.2 and I have a text input field called article summary that is set to format none.

However on the front end the input is getting wrapped in p tags but weirdly enough it's only happening on the first entry.

My code is:

```
<p class="summary">{article_subtitle}</p>
```

And on the front end comes out as:

```
<p class="summary"></p><p>Article Subtitle content</p>
```

I've tried the suggestion on this post but with no luck: [Unformatted Field Data Wrapped in <p> Tags on Output](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/15120/unformatted-field-data-wrapped-in-p-tags-on-output)

Any thoughts?

Comment: What's strange is that it only applies to the first entry in the list...

Comment: What happens if you re-save that entry?

Comment: same. The issue applies to the first entry on each page. http://thisistomorrow.info/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug with the add on Publisher Lite. The developer provided me with a new build to fix it.